# What leaf resembling a mint numbs toothaches?

Tags: dentistry, natural-remedy

While I was on Reddit, I found an interesting claim about a leaf that looks like a mint that can numb toothaches. Here is the exact quote from [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/35ygtj/i_imagine_early_humans_had_poor_dental_hygiene/cr9nub5)

> I do know that some tribes in Cumberland island (along the coast of what is now Georgia) would place **a mint-style leaf** in the side of their mouth to numb tooth aches. I can speak from experience that it is very powerful - I first learned this during a guided tour of the island many years ago.
>
> Here is some more info and a citation.
>
> http://arboretum.ucsc.edu/pdfs/ethnobotany_webversion.pdf

Alas, that link is nonoperative. So to what leaf was the above referring? Is the claim actually true?

Comment: Hi! The link to the arboretum has been changed to [this](http://arboretum.ucsc.edu/index.html). I apologize for not having time at the moment to look through it. Try entering your search parameters on that page and see if what you're looking for comes up. I'll do some research for you tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the leaf you are asking about. But in India we use [Cloves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clove#Traditional_medicinal_uses) since centuries to soothe toothache.

It is a flower bud and very effective against toothaches.

Comment: I agree with your answer although it doesn't point to he mint-like herb. May I suggest a [more reputable source on cloves](http://www.ema.europa.eu/docs/en_GB/document_library/Herbal_-_HMPC_assessment_report/2011/12/WC500119923.pdf). You can always edit your question to improve it :-).